# react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer first connecting attempt returns unable to connect device error, but on second attempt it connects

Tags: react-native, printing, bluetooth

I use react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer. First connection attempt always falls with error `Error: unable to connect device`, but second connects successfully

```
BluetoothManager.connect(this.state.deviceAddr)
        .then((s)=>{
          Alert.alert('connected')
          this.setState({loading: false, connected: true})
        },
        (err)=>{
          //error here
          Alert.alert(err+'')
          this.setState({loading: false})
        })
```

Comment: does your problem resolve?

Comment: I used wifi for printing)

Comment: Ohh good. Could you please share with me the exact package name?

Comment: https://github.com/leesiongchan/react-native-esc-pos